# Annotate stoichiometric numbers below chemical reaction

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry, chemmacros

I use the [chemmacros](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/chemmacros)  packages to write chemical reactions in LaTeX, like this:

```
\ch{CH4 + 2 O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}
```

But now, I want to annotate the stoichiometric numbers below chemical reaction, as the following picture.

I know that **tikz** can do that, but I don't know how. I appreciate your help.

[image: Chemical equation with annotated stoichiometric number]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could exploit the fact that `chemformula` allows relative arbitrary code inside `\ch` between single or double quotes. Although the manual says the escaped code cannot contain spaces, it seems you can get around this by placing the code between braces, which is what I have done below (even though it wasn't actually required in this case).

The `annotate` macro is a bit basic/crude but it should be fairly easy to see how it could be improved. The main problem is how to position the picture nicely relative to the rest of the text and also ignore most of the picture (i.e., the annotation bit).

Below I show a PGF/TikZ way of doing this by using the `baseline` and `trim left`/`trim right` keys.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand\annotate[3][below]{%
\tikz[baseline=0pt,trim left=(@.west), trim right=(@.east)]{%
  \node [draw=orange!50, top color=white, bottom color=orange!25, rounded corners=2pt, inner xsep=1pt,anchor=base](@){#2};
  \node [font=\footnotesize, align=center,inner ysep=2pt, #1=1cm/2 of @] (@') {#3};
  \draw[cyan,-stealth](@)--(@');}%
  \ignorespaces%
}
\begin{document}
\ch{CH4 + "{\annotate{2}{Coeficiente\\estequiom\'etrico}}" O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `"\annotate{2}{Coeficiente\\estequiom\'etrico}"` does not contain spaces so an extra pair of braces is not necessary.

Comment: @cgnierder perhaps that is why the last sentence of the first paragraph of my answer ends in the way it does?

Comment: Ah, maybe! :) I'm actually a bit surprised that braces work for hiding spaces. I know that once upon a time they didn't. I remember a change I made which explains it, though. I should probably update the manual...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the `psmatrix` environment, from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-grad, pst-blur}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows = ->, nodesepA=0pt, nodesepB=2pt, arrowinset=.25, framearc=0.15}
\psset{fillstyle=gradient, gradbegin=white, gradend=LightSalmon1!40! white}
 \begin{psmatrix}
\ce{CH4 + \Rnode{coeff}{\psframebox[linecolor=LightSalmon1!80! white, shadow=true, blur=true, shadowsize =.6pt, blurradius=0.3pt, ]{2}} O2 ―――→ CO2 + 2 H2O}%\\
\uput{7ex}[d](coeff){\Rnode{annot}{\textsf{\footnotesize Coeficiente estequiométrico}}}%
\ncline[linecolor=SkyBlue3]{coeff}{annot}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't this be combined with `chemmacros` (or rather `chemformula`)? If the document contains other formulas they will look typographically very different otherwise...

Comment: @cgnieder: I suppose it can. I simply could not test since I do not have `chemmacros` installed. Looking at chemmacros documentation in the TeX Catalogue, the syntax looked very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Another PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-grad, pst-blur}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
 \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows = ->, arrowinset=.25, framearc=0.15, 
  fillstyle=gradient, gradbegin=white, gradend=LightSalmon1!40! white}
\def\Annote#1#2{\rnode[b]{coeff}{\psframebox[linecolor=LightSalmon1!80! white, 
  shadow, blur, shadowsize =.6pt, blurradius=0.3pt]{#1}%
  \uput{7ex}[-90](coeff){\textsf{\footnotesize\shortstack{#2}}}%
  \ncline[linecolor=SkyBlue3,offsetB=-6.5ex,nodesep=-1.4ex]{coeff}{coeff}}}
 \begin{document}

 \ch{CH4 + "{\Annote{2}{Coeficiente\\estequiométrico}}" O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}

 \end{document}
```

[image]